# Intuition behind pre-multiplication of a vector with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-rank

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and a vector $\mathbf{x}$, the MVP $\mathbf{Ax}$ gives the geometric interpretation of transforming $\mathbf{x}$ into the coordinate system with basis vectors defined by the columns of $\mathbf{A}$. Does such an interpretation exist when a vector $\mathbf{y}$ is pre-multiplied to a matrix, i.e., $\mathbf{yA}$? One interpretation is in terms of the transpose of $\mathbf{A}$, but I'm looking for an explanation in terms of $\mathbf{A}$ itself.

Comment: One thing to consider is that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, we typically assume vectors are written as $n\times 1$ matrices so that $Ax$ makes sense. If that's the convention then $xA$ really means $x^TA$. This makes me suspect that any answer will somehow involve the transpose of $A$ / the dual map.

Comment: What if $\mathbf{A}$ is rectangular? Also, $\mathbf{x}^T$ may not be the same as $\mathbf{y}$ in the question.

Comment: The natural framework in which such notations are "natural" is "duality" (a column vector is... a vector and a row vector is a linear form). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form).